# How to count rows between sheets with repeated primary key

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with several sheets. I need to count 'Function' rows (non empty) by searching for a primary key. The problem is that in a sheet I have the primary key repeated more times and the corresponding column (that i want to count) has a description never the same and sometimes is empty.

```
First sheet 
| PrimayKey|     Function     | 
|:---------|:----------------:| 
| APP0001  |   Administrator  | 
| APP0001  |      user        | 
| APP0001  |      viewer      | 
| APP0001  |                  |
| APP0051  |      user        |
| APP0067  |                  |
| APP0067  |      not         |
| APP0067  |      free        |
| APP0067  |                  |

Other sheet
| Primay Key | N°_Function | 
|:---------- |:-----------:|
|  APP0001   |       3     | 
|  APP0051   |       1     | 
|  APP0067   |      ???    |
```

N°_Function is what I'm looking for. So, for each APP00.. on second sheet excel must search on first sheet this key and, summing the functions, type them on second sheet.
As I've told on first sheet there are empty function cells.

I want an interactive file so I can't use a PIVOT but I need a formula that communicate between sheets. The formula must be written on the second sheet.

For example, how do you print a solution for code APP0067?

Thanks to everyone that will try

Comment: vlookup is no good?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A,`Sheet2`!A2,`Sheet1`!B:B,"<>")` you may need to change the ranges to actual ranges and sheet names (and preferably use tables and table references).